# Excluding Bash File from modifying itself

Tags: bash, grep, find, for

I'm learning how to make script "fool-proof". I have some scripts that modify files in the current folder but they also modify the script itself. I know it all boils down to the "for" loop with "find" I can't get right.

```
for f in $(find . -type f | grep -v $0)
```

My goal is to include all files it can find from the current catalogue and it's sub-catalogues but exclude the executed script itself. It's working with grep -v but now it's excluding every file that includes the name of the script (like copies of the script in the subfolders). Anyone knows how to make it work only for the executed script? I must assume someone might change the name at some point, so excluding it by hand is out of the question.

Comment: Lose the `grep`.  Use `find . -type f ! -path $0` ?

Comment: Tried that already since most answers suggest that. It's not working at all. It's including everything.

Comment: Why not simply move the script to another place, like one directory up or to a dedicated directory for executables, such as `$HOME/local/bin` or similar?

Comment: This is a non-problem.  The `rm` executable does not prevent a user with the right privileges from deleting it.  It's just that it more often applied to other files.  Likewise, just move your script.

Comment: It is impossible to make anything foolproof because fools are so ingenious.

Comment: It might sound silly but I can't get over this problem. I want to find an answer, especially now. It's not like I'm trying to make it "impossible" to break, I'm not naive. I just wanted to figure out the way to protect a script from overwriting itself by implementing the safety mechanism inside it. I thought it would be rather easy but now I see it's more tricky than I've imagined. Nothing seems to work for now. It's either excluding lots of files or none of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of the `find . -type f ! -path $0` approach.  Note how the script only reports the `foo.sh` within the **"d"** directory.  Not the `foo.sh` in the current directory.

```
$ find . -print
.
./a
./b
./c
./foo.sh
./d
./d/foo.sh
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
for f in $(find . -type f ! -path $0); do
echo $f
done
$ ./foo.sh
./a
./b
./c
./d/foo.sh
$
```

Alternatively, try `for f in $(find . -type f | grep -v "^\./foo\.sh$"); do`

Comment: `grep -vxF "$0"` for that last bit, but why `grep` pathnames at all as they may contain embedded newlines.

Comment: @steve Thank you! Your alternative is working like I've wanted to make it work! It really helped me with understanding how to adress files in grep. Gonna experiment on other variations now :)

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with:

```
for f in $(find . -type f); do
 case $f in 
  */$0|$0)
     continue
  ;;
  *)
     echo 'Do something'
  ;;
 esac
 fi
done
```

Comment: What if there is _another_ file down in the directories with the same name as the script that one _does_ want the script to process?  Also: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)

Comment: I know, but the user wants to loop it. If the file has *exactly* the same name, it will be not processed. But if it have a similar name but not exactly the same name it will be ignored.... but with only a simple adjust this behavior can be corrected...